# Responsively position an image at specific target over background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, position

I have a responsive background image with a smaller image positioned over it.  I am trying to keep the smaller image at a specific location when the window is resized.

Both images scale properly, and the left position works so far, but not the top position.

```
img {
max-width:100%;
}

#dot {
position: absolute;
top: 17%;
left: 66.5%;
width: 10%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 10%;
```

}

I have found some questions with answers that suggest:

Vertical Alignment or Positioning with Javascript

I've also looked into .position() and .offset(), not sure if either would work.

I think my best solution would be to calculate the Y offset using the current window height as a reference but I am not sure what my JS or Jquery code should look like.

Here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/melissadpelletier/xBu79/21/

Comment: Is that the entirety of your code? If so, you have a ton of errors by not closing your <div> tags.

Comment: closed my tags. The little bit of css just illustrates my problem.  Did you try to resize the window height with my original code?

Comment: Check out the answer I posted. You will need to rework it a bit to make it work as you would expect, but at least it provides the basic functionality you desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are definitely gonna need some javascript for this. What you can do is calculate the height and width of the image whenever you resize your browser window. Then simply use some math to calculate the position of the dot relative to those dimensions.

```
var height = $('#image').height();
var width = $('#image').width();

/* change the fractions here according to your desired percentages */
$('#dot').css({left: width/2, top: height/2});

$(window).resize(function() {
    height = $('#image').height();
    width = $('#image').width();

    /* change the fractions here according to your desired percentages */
    $('#dot').css({left: width/2, top: height/2});
});
```

Try this code: http://jsfiddle.net/LimitedWard/FFQt2/3/

Note that you will need to also resize the dot according to the height/width of the image if you want it to always fit inside that box.

Edit: after further investigation, it is possible to do this in CSS; however, it's a lot sloppier because the dot doesn't follow the image if the window is too wide. This jQuery solves that problem by using pixel-based positioning.

Comment: This is awesome.  Its exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do with your images, but you could create a new smaller image (green dot) with the same aspect ratio as your background image, and have the dot placed where it needs to be within that aspect ratio.  Then stretch the width of that to be 100% and the two images are basically overlapping, but the top image (smaller image) has a transparent background.  Not sure if that all makes sense, but I made a new image and did the fiddle thing, which I'm new to:  http://jsfiddle.net/ydack/

```
img 
{
width:100%;
}

#dot
{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

#dotImg
{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I mistakenly placed the green dot's position based on the black outline, not the full background image, so the dot is slightly up and right of where it needs to be.  BUT, the position is maintained while re-sizing the window.  Hacky, but it could work!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to come up with a solution.  This would work if I didnt need the code to also work for a css sprite - I'm not sure I would be able to use a full screen width image in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/sajrashid/xBu79/24/

plenty of errors mainly not closing tags

```
<div id='background'>
  <img src='http://i.imgur.com/57fZEOt.png'/>
  <div id='dot'>
    <img src='http://i.imgur.com/yhngPvm.png'/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't believe that solves her problem. You used pixel-based positioning whereas she wanted the position of the dot relative to the image as it resized.